# Accessing a non-Metro COM DLL from a Metro application

Tags: windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I'm aware you aren't supposed to do this, but unfortunately, given the infancy of the WinRT library and the dearth of support of 3rd party controls, I have no other possible solution but to try and use our current charting library with a Metro application.

We have no intention of distributing the application via the App Store.  We hand select and load our application for use by our customers.

I've seen articles where it is possible to manually call, say, MessageBoxA from inside a Metro application successfully by manually loading the applicable DLL, which are still available on the system.

our charting control is distributed as a COM DLL.  Metro blows up if I try to link it normally, which is what I would expect.

I'm curious if there is any way to manually call this DLL from inside a Metro application?

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't even know you had that option.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this myself, but I think it might work:

If you are not interested in publishing your application in the Windows Store, you could try including your COM DLL in your application package, and instanciating your COM objects manually.

The process is explained in [this post](https://www.amyuni.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2438). It's basically about using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the function `DllGetClassObject` that every COM dll contains, and using the GUID of your COM class to get an instance.

In your case, if you create your project as a Windows Store application the function LoadLibrary will not be available, but you can still use [LoadPackageLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.